# Capitalize words in XSLT 1.0

Tags: strings, xslt

Since XSLT 1.0 doesn't have a lot of convenience functions, I have had to cobble them myself. The below capitalizes "words" in a string as defined by a string of delimiters. Is there any way to improve it?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

    <xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="digit" select="'0123456789'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="alnum" select="concat(concat($upper, $lower), $digit)"/>

    <!-- Example usage:

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="input" select="'i-only@had a*very%rudimentary_education-by:anna#russell'"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="cap-words">
            <!- Use anything not alphanumeric as a delimiter. ->
            <xsl:with-param name="delimiters" select="translate($input, $alnum, '')"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="s" select="$input"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    Outputs: IOnlyHadAVeryRudimentaryEducationByAnnaRussell -->

    <xsl:template name="capitalize">
        <!-- Capitalize all the letters in a string -->
        <xsl:param name="s"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate($s, $lower, $upper)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="cap-first">
        <!-- Capitalize the first letter in a string -->
        <xsl:param name="s"/>
        <!-- Use the FP convention of x:xs for recurring on a list -->
        <xsl:variable name="x" select="substring($s, 1, 1)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="xs" select="substring($s, 2)"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="capitalize">
            <xsl:with-param name="s" select="$x"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:value-of select="$xs"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="cap-words">
        <!-- Capitalize the first letter of each word as determined by delimiters. -->
        <xsl:param name="delimiters"/>
        <xsl:param name="s"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($s)">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length($delimiters)">
                    <!-- Use the FP convention of x:xs for recurring on a list -->
                    <xsl:variable name="d" select="substring($delimiters, 1, 1)"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="ds" select="substring($delimiters, 2)"/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="cap-words">
                        <xsl:with-param name="delimiters" select="$ds"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="s">
                            <!-- substring-before and -after return the empty string if the delimiter isn't in the string -->
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="contains($s, $d)">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($s, $d)"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$s"/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <xsl:call-template name="cap-words">
                        <xsl:with-param name="delimiters" select="$ds"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="s" select="substring-after($s, $d)"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:call-template name="cap-first">
                        <xsl:with-param name="s" select="$s"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you using c# or vb.net?

Comment: I'm using xslt 1.0. I'm not using c# or vb.net. My current target is [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html). I have multiple real-world uses for this, but in at least one case I'm using it as part of a larger codebase to create abstract classes in php from xsd.